# Not enough resources available eucalyptus describe availability zones

Tags: ubuntu, eucalyptus

Weird problem "Not enough resources available"
Shivani Rao Aug 24, 2012 01:28AM UTC

I created 4 instances and they were running and I now wanted to create volumes and attach them to the running instances. Unfortunately, even after attaching the volumes, on /dev/sdb partitions, I was not able to see the partition from within in the instance

One of the possible solutions suggested was to set USE_VIRTIO_ROOT=1 in the eucalyptus.conf file. And then the instruction was to initiate a instance reboot from within the instance to which the volume is attached. This shut down all the instances and worse made them all unavailable.

I started getting the "Not enough resources available: vm resources." which is basically because bad configuration settings in the cc.

AVAILABILITYZONE RVLCirrus xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
AVAILABILITYZONE |- vm types free / max cpu ram disk
AVAILABILITYZONE |- m1.small 0000 / 0000 1 192 2
AVAILABILITYZONE |- c1.medium 0000 / 0000 1 256 5
AVAILABILITYZONE |- m1.large 0000 / 0000 2 512 10
AVAILABILITYZONE |- m1.xlarge 0000 / 0000 2 1024 20
AVAILABILITYZONE |- c1.xlarge 0000 / 0000 4 2048 20

The node controller is installed on a separate machine where the nodes actually are. The cluster controller, the cloud controller, the walrus are all sitting on one machine.

I have been going through logs without much idea of what is happening. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

All the resources of your system are available with 4 instances and no resource left to create partition or attach volume either terminate two instance and make resource available.

Comment: how I can check that the resources of my system are available or no resource left?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems

1. Credentials are not sourced. On Front end machine, run command

   > [root@clc]# mkdir /home/abc/euca-cred
   >
   > [root@clc]# cd /home/abc/euca-cred
   >
   > [root@clc]# euca_conf --get-credentials -o admin.zip
   >
   > [root@clc]# unzip admin.zip
   >
   > [root@clc]# source eucarc
   >
   > [root@clc]# euca-describe-availability-zones verbose
2. NTP is not synchronized with server.

   > [root@nc]# ntpdate -u CLC_IP_address

These are the possible reasons might solve your problem.