# Error when launching an instance "not enough resources vm instances"

Tags: eucalyptus

I was able to use the web interface but I get this error when launching an instance. "Not enough resources (0 in cluster1 < 1): vm instances."

I installed Eucalyptus 4 manually on a single physical server running CentOS 6.5 (minimal)

Various articles I found, including this one URL below, mention that the Node Controller is not registered.  Apparently evidence of this (shown below) is the "free/max" column is showing all zeros (0000)
http://opensource.sys-con.com/node/1349819

This command in the instructions seemed to register ok when I did it:

```
[root@server2 eucaconsole]# /usr/sbin/euca_conf --register-nodes "172.17.1.22"
INFO: We expect all nodes to have eucalyptus installed in $EUCALYPTUS for key synchronization. 
root@172.17.1.22's password:
...done
```

The command given in the article has a parameter that's not supported (maybe deprecated)

```
[root@server2 eucaconsole]# euca_conf --no-rsync --discover-nodes
Usage: euca_conf [options]
euca_conf: error: no such option: --discover-nodes
```

Below is my output that shows all zeros in the "free" and "max" columns

```
[root@server2 eucaconsole]# euca-describe-availability-zones verbose
AVAILABILITYZONE        cluster1        172.17.1.22 arn:euca:eucalyptus:cluster1:cluster:cc-22/
AVAILABILITYZONE        |- vm types     free / max   cpu   ram  disk
AVAILABILITYZONE        |- m1.small     0000 / 0000   1    256     5
AVAILABILITYZONE        |- t1.micro     0000 / 0000   1    256     5
AVAILABILITYZONE        |- m1.medium    0000 / 0000   1    512    10
AVAILABILITYZONE        |- c1.medium    0000 / 0000   2    512    10
AVAILABILITYZONE        |- m1.large     0000 / 0000   2    512    10
AVAILABILITYZONE        |- m1.xlarge    0000 / 0000   2   1024    10
AVAILABILITYZONE        |- c1.xlarge    0000 / 0000   2   2048    10
AVAILABILITYZONE        |- m2.xlarge    0000 / 0000   2   2048    10
AVAILABILITYZONE        |- m3.xlarge    0000 / 0000   4   2048    15
AVAILABILITYZONE        |- m2.2xlarge   0000 / 0000   2   4096    30
AVAILABILITYZONE        |- m3.2xlarge   0000 / 0000   4   4096    30
AVAILABILITYZONE        |- cc1.4xlarge  0000 / 0000   8   3072    60
AVAILABILITYZONE        |- m2.4xlarge   0000 / 0000   8   4096    60
AVAILABILITYZONE        |- hi1.4xlarge  0000 / 0000   8   6144   120
AVAILABILITYZONE        |- cc2.8xlarge  0000 / 0000  16   6144   120
AVAILABILITYZONE        |- cg1.4xlarge  0000 / 0000  16   12288   200
AVAILABILITYZONE        |- cr1.8xlarge  0000 / 0000  16   16384   240
AVAILABILITYZONE        |- hs1.8xlarge  0000 / 0000  48   119808  24000
```

The most relevant article I could find on the community forum on StackOverflow only found this which didn't help me.
[Not enough resources available eucalyptus describe availability zones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102160/not-enough-resources-available-eucalyptus-describe-availability-zones)

Thanks in advance if anyone help me fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `euca-describe-nodes`

if you get output similar to the following -

> NODE   PARTI00     10.111.5.176    ENABLED

Then your node is properly registered. One common problem is the lack of diskspace. If you do the normal CentOS 6.5 minimal install, it will sometimes create a separate partition for /home and put the lion's share of space in that partition. Check your eucalyptus.conf for the `INSTANCE_PATH` variable and whatever directory that points to, make sure it is located on a partition with a lot of space.

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in `/etc/eucalyptus/eucalyptus.conf`, search for `Max_Cores`, and change the number of instances you want to launch. this solved the issues